# Recover Jenkins username and password

Tags: windows, jenkins

how can we reset the username and password in windows for Jenkins.
or is there a way to uninstall Jenkins completely so that when I reinstall it , I can again create a username and password?

Any solutions would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

You can simply delete the entire JENKINS_HOME directory and then restart the server. This will prompt you to the new setup wizard.

### Option 2

Open JENKINS_HOME/config.xml and disable security by setting the following.

```
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

Then access Jenkins and open the `Script Console`(JENKINS_URL/script). Execute the following script to create a new user.

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*

def j = Jenkins.getInstance()

def realm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false)
realm.createAccount("newadmin","newpass")
j.setSecurityRealm(realm)
j.save()
```

Now enable security again and login to Jenkins with the new user.

**Additional**

If you want to recover the old user. After following the above steps open the file `JENKINS_HOME/users/newadmin_RANDOM_NUMBER/config.xml` and copy the following two values `seed` and `passwordHash` to the old admins config.xml(If the old admins username is `admin` the file should be located at `JENKINS_HOME/users/admin_RANDOM_NUMBER/config.xml`)

```
<jenkins.security.seed.UserSeedProperty>
   <seed>405397d771ce33e7</seed>
</jenkins.security.seed.UserSeedProperty>

and

<hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm_-Details>    
    <passwordHash>#jbcrypt:$2a$10$UGYgHccQxAd9V6neqfJxx.......</passwordHash>
</hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm_-Details>
```

Then restart the server and you should be able to use the password of `newadmin` for `admin`.